# Javascript function not recognizing id in getElementById

Tags: javascript, html

I am adding a row to a table, and attached an `ondblclick` event to the cells.  The function `addrow` is working fine, and the `dblclick` is taking me to `seltogg`, with the correct parameters.  However, the `var selbutton = document.getElementById` in `seltogg` is returning a null.  When I call `seltogg` with a `dblclick` on the original table in the document, it runs fine.  All the parameters "`selna`" have alphabetic values, with no spaces, special characters, etc.  Can someone tell me why seltogg is unable to correctly perform the `document.getElementById` when I pass the id from `addrow`; also how to fix the problem.

```
function addrow(jtop, sel4list, ron4list) {
    var tablex = document.getElementById('thetable');
    var initcount = document.getElementById('numrows').value;
    var sel4arr = sel4list.split(",");
    var idcount = parseInt(initcount) + 1;
    var rowx = tablex.insertRow(1);
    var jtop1 = jtop - 1;

    for (j = 0; j <= jtop1; j++) {
        var cellx = rowx.insertCell(j);
        cellx.style.border = "1px solid blue";

        var inputx = document.createElement("input");

        inputx.type = "text";
        inputx.ondblclick = (function() {
            var curj = j;
            var selna = sel4arr[curj + 2];
            var cellj = parseInt(curj) + 3;
            inputx.id = "cell_" + idcount + "_" + cellj;
            var b = "cell_" + idcount + "_" + cellj;
            return function() {
                seltogg(selna, b);
            }
        })();

        cellx.appendChild(inputx);
    } //end j loop
    var rowCount = tablex.rows.length;
    document.getElementById('numrows').value = rowCount - 1; //dont count header
} //end function addrow

function seltogg(selna, cellid) {
    if (selna == "none") {
        return;
    }
    document.getElementById('x').value = cellid; //setting up for the next function
    var selbutton = document.getElementById(selna); //*****this is returning null
    if (selbutton.style.display != 'none') { //if it's on
        selbutton.style.display = 'none';
    } //turn it off               
    else { //if it's off
        selbutton.style.display = '';
    } //turn it on  
} //end of function seltogg
```

Comment: document.getElementById only return null when the id you provide does not exist

Comment: You haven't really shown enough here in order for anyone to figure out what you're doing wrong; we can't see what's in `sel4list`, and we can't see all the IDs that actually *do* exist in your HTML document.

Comment: Have you confirmed the value of `selna` is an element ID?  It looks like `sel4arr` is set to an array in `addrow`, but not in the `ondblclick` function.

Comment: Have you tried just calling seltogg(...) instead of return function(){ seltogg(...)} ?

Comment: Ruakh, sel4list is simply the valid selnas, and each is indeed in the DOM -- evidence is that seltogg works exactly right when called by a dblclick from the DOM.  Don't know what code I could show you to prove this, as everything is dynamic; but it was the first thing I checked out.  Wish that were the problem -- then I could solve it.

Comment: Found the answer -- it is instructive.  I tried documents.getElementsById("select") and the id's it was showing are not the id's in the document.  It was picking them up from the wrong document (call it docA) , because the docA had been included in the correct document (docB).  I had renamed selna in docB, but I forgot I had done that.  My bad.  Thank you all for trying to help.

Comment: make that document.getElementByTagName("select") ..

Answer (score 1):

You try, writing this sentence:
`document.getElementById("numrows").value`  on `document.getElementById('numrows').value`

This is my part the my code:

```
contapara=(parseInt(contapara)+1);

                document.getElementById("sorpara").innerHTML+="<li id=\"inputp"+contapara+"_id\" class=\"ui-state-default\"><span class=\"ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s\"></span>"+$('#inputp'+contapara+'_id').val()+"</li>";
```

Look you have to use this " y not '.
TRY!!!!

Comment: the document.getElementById("numrows") statement is working fine.  It does not need to be changed.  Betty